# How can I throttle async functions in .Net?

Tags: .net, async-await, throttling

I'm using async-await in .Net.  How can I limit the number of concurrent asynchronous calls?

Comment: Have you looked at TPL with WithDegreeOfParallelism?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx

Comment: How are you using `await`?  There is only one asynchronous call at at a time.  e.g. `await SomethingAsync(); await SomethingElseAsync();`:  `SomethingElseAsync` won't be called until `SomethingAsync` completes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One relatively simple way is to (ab)use TPL Dataflow. Something like:

```
public IEnumerable<TOutput> AsyncThrottle<TInput, TOutput>(
    IEnumerable<TInput> inputs, Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> asyncFunction,
    int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
{
    var outputs = new ConcurrentQueue<TOutput>();

    var block = new ActionBlock<TInput>(
        async x => outputs.Enqueue(await asyncFunction(x)),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        { MaxDgreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism });

    foreach (var input in inputs)
        block.Send(input);

    block.Complete();
    block.Completion.Wait();

    return outputs.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Off-hand, it seems like Parallel.ForEach would be simpler and still accomplish this?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because `Parallel.ForEach()` doesn't support `async`. You want to start a new `Task` only after a previous one completed and the only way to achieve that with `Parallel.ForEach()` would be if you explicitly called `Wait()` (which is obviously undesirable).

Comment: I don't see an ActionBlock generic with two paramenters in VB.Net, just one parameter.  How do I get the result?  It would be nice to have this capability wrapped in a generic function.

Comment: @Eyal Sorry, you're right. See my edited answer for one way of doing that.

Comment: So how do I get the return values from GetBitmapAsync in this case?  I don't see how TPL Dataflow fits in async-await.  Why should we need both?  And this requires that each action perform the same operation: GetBitmapAsync.  What if I want to limt the concurrency of different functions?  Seems... inelegant.  Would there be a away to wrap this idea in a function like I wrote?

Comment: @Eyal You get the bitmaps from the `bitmaps` collection. And `async`/`await` doesn't do what you want by itself, so you need *something*. That something may as well be TPL Dataflow. If you want to perform different actions, you could use delegates: `new ActionBlock<Func<Task>>(async f => await f())`.

Comment: Okay.  An answer that works for bitmaps is fine.  I was thinking about something generic, however.  I'll try to wrap this in a class and make something generally useful...  As soon as VS2012 stops crashing!

Comment: But you have to provide all the inputs as a list.  I have a loop over each of the elements in a listview, for instance, and nested a few levels deep, there are some functions that I would like to throttle.  It's not nearly as convenient as the async-await model where each call takes one input and returns one task.  Also, it's nice to have the task, for using await later.

Comment: @Eyal You could do that too, using the delegate-executing block I mentioned earlier. And I think it would also involve using `TaskCompletionSource`, because you need to return some `Task` early, even before the delegate is executed.

Comment: @svick: Yup, I figured out the `TaskCompleteSource` requirement when I realized that I need to return a task before I even start one!  I thought that I could chain the results of `WhenAny` but it's too difficult to get the correct list input, which is changing over time, and all those continuations are inelegant anyway.  I added the solution below.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it's simple and it works.  If a list of the input tasks isn't possible, however, I humbly propose my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I leave this here for legacy.  Don't do it this way because there will be too many tasks waiting on the `WhenAny` simultaneously.  And the stack will get deep.

Based on this code by Stephen Toub:

```
const int CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 15;
Uri [] urls = …;
int nextIndex = 0;
var imageTasks = new List<Task<Bitmap>>();
while(nextIndex < CONCURRENCY_LEVEL && nextIndex < urls.Length)
{
    imageTasks.Add(GetBitmapAsync(urls[nextIndex]));
    nextIndex++;
}

while(imageTasks.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        Task<Bitmap> imageTask = await Task.WhenAny(imageTasks);
        imageTasks.Remove(imageTask);

        Bitmap image = await imageTask;
        panel.AddImage(image);
    }
    catch(Exception exc) { Log(exc); }

    if (nextIndex < urls.Length)
    {
        imageTasks.Add(GetBitmapAsync(urls[nextIndex]));
        nextIndex++;
    }
}
```

I wrote this:

```vb
Private ThrottleGroups As New Dictionary(Of Object, List(Of Task))
Public Async Function ThrottleAsync(Of TResult)(ByVal f As Func(Of Task(Of TResult)), GroupId As Object, MaxCount As Integer) As Task(Of TResult)
    If Not ThrottleGroups.ContainsKey(GroupId) Then
        ThrottleGroups.Add(GroupId, New List(Of Task))
    End If
    If ThrottleGroups(GroupId).Count < MaxCount Then
        Dim NewTask As Task(Of TResult) = f()
        ThrottleGroups(GroupId).Add(NewTask)
        Return Await NewTask
    Else
        Dim FinishedTask As Task = Await Task.WhenAny(ThrottleGroups(GroupId))
        ThrottleGroups(GroupId).Remove(FinishedTask)
        Return Await ThrottleAsync(f, GroupId, MaxCount)
    End If
End Function
```

To use, just replace:

```vb
ExampleTaskAsync(param1, param2)
```

with:

```vb
Dim f As Func(Of Task(Of Integer))
f = Function()
        Return ExampleAsync(param1, param2)
    End Function
Const CONCURRENT_TASKS As Integer = 4
Return ThrottleAsync(f, "ExampleAsync", CONCURRENT_TASKS)
```

Notice that we have to wrap the call to the task in a function `f` because otherwise we would be already starting the Task.  The second parameter to ThrottleAsync is any object that identifies the "group"; I used a string.  All asynchronous tasks in the same "group" are limited to `CONCURRENT_TASKS` tasks, in this case 4.

Here's sample code that show how only four threads run at a time.  `All Ready!` displays immediately because the subroutine is asynchronous.  Also, even if the threads start or end out of order, the "output" lines will still be in the same order as the input.

```vb
Dim results As New List(Of Task(Of Integer))
    For i As Integer = 0 To 20
        Dim j As Integer = i
        Dim f As Func(Of Task(Of Integer))
        f = Function() As Task(Of Integer)
                Return Task.Run(Function() As Integer
                                    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "Starting " & j)
                                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                                    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "Ending " & j)
                                    Return j
                                End Function)
            End Function
        Const CONCURRENT_UPLOADS As Integer = 4
        results.Add(ThrottleAsync(f, "PutOjbectAsync", CONCURRENT_UPLOADS))
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("all ready!")
    For Each x As Task(Of Integer) In results
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "Output: " & Await x)
    Next
```

Comment: Your previous questions are already pointing you towards TPL Dataflow. Why not go with svick's simple answer rather than implementing it yourself?

Comment: I think your code is not thread-safe, `Remove()` could be called from several threads at the same time. I think you should use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead.

Comment: @Stephen: Here's why I'm not using TPL: It crashes VS2012 consistenly: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762959/editor-crash-when-using-tpl  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the code, the simplest approach might be using Parallel.For(Each) and specify the max parallelism in the parallel options.

Comment: I don't think it would, `Parallel.For(Each)` doesn't work well with `async` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I like this technique better.  I'm using `TaskCompletionSource` to create output tasks for the incoming tasks.  This is necessary because I want to return a `Task` before I even run it!  The class below associates each input `Func(of Task(of Object))` with a `TaskCompletionSource` which is returned immediately and puts them into a queue.

Elements from the queue are dequeued into a list of running tasks and a continuation sets the `TaskCompletionSource`.  An invocation to `WhenAny` in a loop makes sure to move elements from the queue to the running list when room frees up.  There's also a check to make sure that there isn't more than one `WhenAny` at a time, though it might have concurrency issues.

To use, just replace synchronous functions like this:

```vb
Task.Run(AddressOf MySyncFunction) 'possibly many of these
```

with this:

```vb
Dim t1 As New Throttler(4)
t1.Run(AddressOf MySyncFunction) 'many of these, but only 4 will run at a time.
```

For functions which already return a Task, it's important to convert those into functions that return Task so that the thottler can run them.  Replace:

```vb
NewTask = MyFunctionAsync()
```

with:

```vb
NewTask = t1.Run(Function () return MyFunctionAsync())
```

The class below also implements many different signatures for Throttler.Run() depending on whether the function is sync/async, has/hasn't input, has/hasn't output.  Converting Task to Task(Of Output) is especially tricky!

```vb
Class Throttler
    Property MaxCount As Integer

    Sub New(Optional MaxCount As Integer = 1)
        Me.MaxCount = MaxCount
    End Sub

    Private Running As New List(Of Task)
    Private Waiting As New Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of System.Tuple(Of Func(Of Task(Of Object)), TaskCompletionSource(Of Object)))
    Private AlreadyWaiting As Boolean

    Async Sub MakeWaiter()
        If AlreadyWaiting Then Exit Sub
        AlreadyWaiting = True
        Do While Waiting.Count > 0
            Dim CurrentWait As System.Tuple(Of Func(Of Task(Of Object)), TaskCompletionSource(Of Object)) = Nothing
            Do While Running.Count < MaxCount AndAlso Waiting.TryDequeue(CurrentWait)
                Dim NewFunc As Func(Of Task(Of Object)) = CurrentWait.Item1
                Dim NewTask As Task(Of Object) = NewFunc()
                Dim CurrentTcs As TaskCompletionSource(Of Object) = CurrentWait.Item2
                NewTask.ContinueWith(Sub(t2 As Task(Of Object))
                                         CurrentTcs.SetResult(t2.Result)
                                     End Sub)
                Running.Add(NewTask)
            Loop
            If Waiting.Count > 0 Then
                Dim Waiter As Task(Of Task)
                Waiter = Task.WhenAny(Running)
                Dim FinishedTask As Task = Await Waiter
                Await FinishedTask
                Running.Remove(FinishedTask)
            End If
        Loop
        AlreadyWaiting = False
    End Sub

    Function Run(f As Func(Of Task(Of Object))) As Task(Of Object)
        Dim NewTcs As New TaskCompletionSource(Of Object)
        Waiting.Enqueue(New System.Tuple(Of Func(Of Task(Of Object)), TaskCompletionSource(Of Object))(f, NewTcs))
        MakeWaiter()
        Return NewTcs.Task
    End Function

    Function Run(Of TInput)(f As Func(Of TInput, Task), input As TInput) As Task
        Dim NewF As Func(Of Task)
        NewF = Function() As Task
                   Return f(input)
               End Function
        Return Me.Run(NewF)
    End Function

    Function Run(Of TInput)(f As Func(Of TInput, Task(Of Object)), input As TInput) As Task(Of Object)
        Dim NewF As Func(Of Task(Of Object))
        NewF = Function() As Task(Of Object)
                   Return f(input)
               End Function
        Return CType(Me.Run(NewF), Task(Of Object))
    End Function

    Function Run(f As Func(Of Task)) As Task
        Dim NewF As Func(Of Task(Of Object))
        NewF = Function() As Task(Of Object)
                   Return f().ContinueWith(Function(t As task) As Object
                                               Return Nothing
                                           End Function)
               End Function
        Return CType(Me.Run(NewF), Task(Of Object))
    End Function

    Function Run(Of TInput)(f As Func(Of TInput, Object), input As TInput) As Task(Of Object)
        Dim NewF As Func(Of Task(Of Object))
        NewF = Function() As Task(Of Object)
                   Return Task.Run(Function() As Object
                                       Return f(input)
                                   End Function)
               End Function
        Return CType(Me.Run(NewF), Task(Of Object))
    End Function

    Function Run(Of TInput)(f As Action(Of TInput), input As TInput) As Task
        Dim NewF As Func(Of Task)
        NewF = Function() As Task
                   Return Task.Run(Sub()
                                       f(input)
                                   End Sub)
               End Function
        Return Me.Run(NewF)
    End Function

    Function Run(f As Func(Of Object)) As Task(Of Object)
        Dim NewF As Func(Of Task(Of Object))
        NewF = Function() As Task(Of Object)
                   Return Task.Run(Function()
                                       Return f()
                                   End Function)
               End Function
        Return CType(Me.Run(NewF), Task(Of Object))
    End Function

    Function Run(f As Action) As Task
        Dim NewF As Func(Of Task)
        NewF = Function() As Task
                   Return Task.Run(Sub()
                                       f()
                                   End Sub)
               End Function
        Return Me.Run(NewF)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: One of the reasons why I prefer something like TPL Datataflow is because I can be sure that it's thread-safe. I think your code isn't thread-safe in several ways. For example, `MakeWaiter()` could run more than once at the same time, because you're not using `AlreadyWaiting` atomically.

Comment: I agree.  I changed it to use the Dataflow.ActionBlock together with the TaskCompletionSource that you suggested.

Comment: Actually, I've gone back to using the loop.  The problem with the `ActionBlock` is that I can't get it to run in the correct context.  If it runs in the wrong context, UI manipulation in the task throws an exception.  If it runs in the UI context, the call to Task.Wait halts the UI.  I need for the ActionBlock to run in a new context but the original Task to run in the original context.  I don't see how.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly do you need and you should almost never use `Wait()` in an application that uses `await`, but wouldn't setting [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.taskscheduler) of the block do the trick?

Comment: I need the task to run in UI context so that the operation that it does will work, but I need the ActionBlock to run in threads so that I don't lock up the UI.  And the procedure in the ActionBlock must take time or else I won't get throttling.  If you can make it work, I'd be glad to learn! http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4a4f4a06-49a8-4b5a-8b5a-7d2d473db4f1/view-source